# Java Calculator Remove first line

Tags: java

I need to create a Mortgage Calculator for my Java class, and I have been racking my brain all DAY about how to remove the first line of the results. I need to write a program in Java (without a graphical user interface) using a loan amount of $200,000 with an interest rate of 5.75% and a 30 year term. Then I need to display the mortgage payment amount and then list the loan balance and interest paid for each payment over the term of the loan.

How do I make it so it calculates the monthly payments starting at month 1 and NOT at month 0? I want to remove the first line `$0, $0, $200,000.`

```
import java.text.*;     // Import text formatting classes

public class MortgageCalculator {

    public static void main(String arguments[]) {

        //Variables
        double loanAmount = 200000; // Amount borrowed
        int loanTerm = 360; // Total months of term
        double loanInterest = 0.0575;   // Yearly interest in decimal form

        double monthlyRate = (loanInterest / 12);   //calculate monthly rate

        DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("$###,###.00");    //Formatting the results to decimal form

        // Assign calculation result to monthlyPayment
        double monthlyPayment =
            loanAmount *
            (monthlyRate * Math.pow((1 + monthlyRate), loanTerm)) /
            (Math.pow((1 + monthlyRate), loanTerm) - 1);

        //Print Loan Amount, Interest Rate, Loan Term and Monthly Payment
        System.out.println("The loan amount is: " +
                df.format(loanAmount));

        System.out.println("The intrest rate is: " +
                loanInterest * 100 + "%");

        System.out.println("The term of the loan is: " +
                loanTerm / 12 + " years" + "\n");

        System.out.println("Monthly Payment: " +
                df.format(monthlyPayment) + "\n");

        // New variables

        double balance = loanAmount;
        double monthlyInterest = 0;
        double principal = 0;

        // display 20 lines of results at one time

        // provides columns
        System.out.println("\n\n\nPrincipal\tInterest\tBalance");
        System.out.println("Payment\t\tPayment\t\tRemaining");
        System.out.println("--------- \t--------- \t---------");

        // Start Looping

        int i;

        while (balance > 0) {

            for (i = 1; i < 10; i++) {

                // Display interest, principal, and balance
                System.out.println(df.format(principal) +
                           "\t\t" +
                           df.format(monthlyInterest) +
                           "\t\t" + df.format(balance));

                // New calculations
                monthlyInterest = (balance * monthlyRate);
                principal = (monthlyPayment - monthlyInterest);
                balance = (balance - principal);

            }   // end loop i
            //Pauses screen
            try {
                Thread.sleep(1500);
            }
            catch(InterruptedException e) {
            }
        }       // end while statement

        //Stops loop statement
        if (balance <= 0) {
            System.out.println("The loan balance is: $0.00");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To remove the first line just do the calculations before the `println` method is called.

For example:

```
         for (i = 1; i<10; i++) {

             // New calculations
             monthlyInterest = (balance * monthlyRate);
             principal = (monthlyPayment - monthlyInterest);
             balance = (balance - principal);

             // Display interest, principal, and balance
             System.out.println(df.format(principal) + "\t\t" + df.format(monthlyInterest) + "\t\t" + df.format(balance));

         } // end loop i
```

You also need to adjust `i` in the for-loop accordingly. I think this is what you were asking?

Comment: Thank you @AdamJMTech!! But now my program will not stop when it reaches $0.00. Sorry, I'm really new to Java!

Comment: You can have `if(balance <= 0){ break;}` in the for loop after the calculations, which will terminate the while loop before printing a negative balance. Your best off reworking the loops you have, as I think there may be an easier way rather than nesting the loops.

Comment: Yes, my loops are all wrong!! The last part of my assignment requires "If the list would scroll off the screen, use loops to display a partial list, hesitate, and then display more of the list." My program was working fine until I ran into issues with that part. =/

Comment: I think it would also be better if you broke your program up into separate methods as its very hard to read and mark at the moment. Good luck!

Comment: Thank you for all of your help!!! I will work on cleaning up my code to make it hard to read. At this point I just needed it to work so I can turn it in tonight :) Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

There are various approaches. You coould implement a counter. Your could also check if the amount paid off > 0 before printing

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem lies in the way you're nesting loops. I see that you want to chunk up the output so that it doesn't all dump out at once, but you can easily bring that all into one loop (hint: look at the modulus operator '%'). Then either skip output on the first iteration, using a counter, or check the payment value before printing.

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid there are more pressing problems than the first funny output line:

```
$1,156.04       $11.11      $1,161.58
$1,161.58       $5.57       $.00
$1,167.15       $.00        -$1,167.15
$1,172.74       -$5.59      -$2,339.88
$1,178.36       -$11.21     -$3,518.24
$1,184.00       -$16.86     -$4,702.25
$1,189.68       -$22.53     -$5,891.92
$1,195.38       -$28.23     -$7,087.30
$1,201.11       -$33.96     -$8,288.41
$1,206.86       -$39.72     -$9,495.27
The loan balance is: $0.00
```

There are *eight* payments too many, and the ending balance is very wrong -- `$0.00` when in reality the bank owes the customer nearly ten grand.

I can appreciate that you added the sleep every ten lines for some reasonable reason, but it shouldn't effect the correct calculation of the loan data. I strongly recommend removing the inner loop on `i` and perhaps sleeping every tenth or twentieth line of output (perhaps using the `%` operator on that `int i` that can still be useful :).

Something to consider, if you have enough time before this project is due, is splitting apart your program along a division of duties: Have a function calculate the monthly payment, one function calculate the ratio of principal vs interest, and another routine to print the data to the user. It sounds more complicated this way, but when you need to amend this program in three weeks to provide a graphical output, you'll quickly understand the benefits of keeping *display* routines separate from *computation* routines. (This is part of a larger theory of [model-view-controller](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model_view_controller); if you've got time before this is due, please read through the Wikipedia description and try to understand where it would be useful in this program.)

Comment: Yeah I'm trying to figure out why this problem is happening... Unfortunately this portion of my assignment is due tonight. I have everything working the way I need it to, this is just the last issue. I NEED it to stop at $0.00.

Comment: @Dawn, aha; then a more direct hint: you've got a `for` loop that you use to break apart your responses. It's mucking things up. :)

Comment: Well I got things to work. Added a break and changed while "balance >= 0" to "balance >= 1" to get rid of the negatives. I will work on cleaning up my code next week so it is not so hard to read. THANK YOU SO MUCH!!

Comment: @Dawn, please try your modification `balance >= 1` with a wide variety of input numbers; I really think the safer solution is to remove the `for` loop completely and instead sleep after outputting every tenth line instead. (Or don't sleep at all. Most terminals have reasonable scrollback buffers.)